# My main 'index.js' from my package.json doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, package.json

I dont know why i don't have any result on my console, i made my `package.json` map with `index.js`

PS: I put it in the root of my project

`package.json`:

```
{
 "name": "MyProject",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "main": "index.js",

 "scripts": {
 "start": "node server/index.js",
 "dev": "nodemon server/index.js",
 "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
 "build": "vue-cli-service build",
 "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},

"dependencies": { 
"axios": "^0.25.0",
"body-parser": "^1.19.2",
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"express": "^4.17.3",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"mongoose": "^6.2.3",
"pinia": "^2.0.0-rc.10",
"vue": "^3.0.0",
"vue-router": "^4.0.12"

},
```

My `index.js`

```
import axios from "axios";

const response = axios.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
   
  console.log(response);
```

On my terminal when i type `npm run serve`

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.1.17:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

...but nothing on my console

Comment: What do you expect?! You run `npm run serve` which does nothing with your index.js file. Try to run `npm run start`

Comment: @Marc yep i already try with `start` it doesent run anything, i got this on my console : sockjs.js?9be2:1609          GET http://192.168.1.17:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1646949883816 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Probably need to put `await` before `axios.get` for that response to resolve.

Comment: @allxie i try that but nothing

Comment: If you just put "console.log("My file has loaded") at the bottom of index.js, does it work? async/await has to be used in a function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function